# secondary router outlet inside primary router outlet not working

Tags: angular, router-outlet

I have the following configuration for my router outlets. The secondary router outlet is contained in the primary one. When I try to use routerLink to show the roster.component.html, it throws the following error.I tried many different configurations but I dont understand why it doesnt work.

> ERROR Error: "[object Object]"    resolvePromise
>   http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3159:31    resolvePromise
>   http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3116:17    scheduleResolveOrReject
>   http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3218:17    invokeTask
>   http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2766:17    onInvokeTask
>   http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:73499:24  invokeTask
>   http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2765:17    runTask
>   http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2533:28    drainMicroTaskQueue
>   http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2940:25    invokeTask
>   http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2845:21    invokeTask
>   http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3885:9     globalZoneAwareCallback
>   http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3911:17 core.js:12501

**app.module.ts**

```
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
const appRoutes: Routes = [

  {path: '', component: ProfileComponent},
    {path: 'roster', component: RosterComponent, outlet: 'basis'},

  /*
  {path: '', component: ProfileComponent,children: [
    {path: 'roster', component: RosterComponent, outlet: 'basis'},
  ]}
*/
]
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MainViewComponent,
    ProfileComponent,
    RosterComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**main-view.component.html**

```
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**profile.component.html**

```
<a [routerLink]="[{ outlets:{ primery:['],basis: ['roster'] } }]">GO</a>
 <router-outlet name="basis"></router-outlet>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have some typos, try this:

```
<a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { primary: [''],basis: ['roster'] } }]">
    Go
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Router configuration:

```
{ path: '', component: ProfileComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'roster', component: RosterComponent, },
    ]
  }
```

app.component.html or main-view.component.html

```
<a routerLink="/roster">Go</a>
```

profile.component.html

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```